# Hashicorp Vault revoke SSH signed certificate

Tags: ssh, hashicorp-vault

How to revoke the **SSH signed certificate before ttl** in Hashicorp Vault ?

Comment: Do you want to override the default secrets engine TTL when issuing a certificate or do you want to revoke an existing certificate? The former is just a parameter, the latter is not possible.

Comment: I want to revoke the existing signed certificate

Answer (score 1):

Revoking SSH certificates is currently **not possible through Vault**.

The main issue is that SSH certificates do not have the online revocation system that TLS certificates have (either CRL from the CA or OCSP). This means any revocation needs to be propagated through other means.

In openssh, this is done using the `RevokedKeys` option which points to a [key revocation list](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen.1#KEY_REVOCATION_LISTS). This list can contain keys or certificates to reject.

When you want to revoke a certificate, you would need to add it to the revocation list on **every host** that needs to reject it.

There has been at least [one request](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/3377) to add generating certificate revocation lists in Vault but this has been closed. The recommended alternative is very short lived certificate lifetimes (enough to connect right away).